# Resultados JSON duplicados JQUERY/AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Senhores, estou fazendo uma consulta em um URL que me retorna os resultados de jogos, porém esta me mostrando os resultados duplicados, poderiam me dar uma luz de onde posso estar errando?

Aqui onde faço a consulta:

```
var dadosJson = '';
$(".carregando").show();
$.getJSON("https://api.the-odds-api.com/v3/odds/?sport=upcoming&region=us&mkt=h2h&apiKey=e2d83afb38831daf6779f63a47c32d38#", function(retorno){
$.each(retorno.data, function (i) {
      console.log(retorno.data[i]);

$.each(retorno.data[i].sites, function(a, key){

        $.each(retorno.data[i].teams, function(c, key){

            $.each(retorno.data[i].sites[a], function(b, key){

                primeira = retorno.data[i].sites[a].odds.h2h[0];
                segunda = retorno.data[i].sites[a].odds.h2h[2];
                terecira = retorno.data[i].sites[a].odds.h2h[3];

                esporte = retorno.data[i].sport_nice;
                timeMandante = retorno.data[i].home_team;
                times = retorno.data[i].teams[c];
***********AQUI ONDE MONDO O LAYOUT QUE QUERO QUE SEJA RETORNADO*************
})

            $('.esportes').html(dadosJson);

        });
    })
});
$(".carregando").hide(); 
})
```

Segue um print do retorno do JSON no primeiro $.each.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem, porém tem uns erros de digitação e indice. está retornando todo o objeto, só precisa acessar de maneira correta as informações. acredito com essas variáveis que você criou consiga recuperar todas informações corretamente :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>teste</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dadosJson = '';
$.getJSON("https://api.the-odds-api.com/v3/odds/?sport=upcoming&region=us&mkt=h2h&apiKey=e2d83afb38831daf6779f63a47c32d38#", function(retorno){
$.each(retorno.data, function (i) {
      console.log(retorno.data[i]);

$.each(retorno.data[i].sites, function(a, key){

        $.each(retorno.data[i].teams, function(c, key){

            $.each(retorno.data[i].sites[a], function(b, key){

                primeira = retorno.data[i].sites[a].odds.h2h[0];
                segunda = retorno.data[i].sites[a].odds.h2h[1];
                terceira = retorno.data[i].sites[a].odds.h2h[2];

                esporte = retorno.data[i].sport_nice;
                timeMandante = retorno.data[i].home_team;
                times = retorno.data[i].teams[c];
// ***********AQUI ONDE MONDO O LAYOUT QUE QUERO QUE SEJA RETORNADO*************
})

            console.log(primeira);
            console.log(segunda);
            console.log(terceira);
            console.log(esporte); //ex bundesliga germany   
            console.log(timeMandante); //time da casa
            console.log(times); //time adversario

            return (dadosJson);

        });
    })
});

})
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Sobre adicionar apenas 10, é possível sim, porém, para falar a verdade teria que fazer requisição ajax, e passar pro arquivo a data que recuperou do json, e assim podendo manipular as informações server side, com php. Dai é fazer paginação e colocar os valores na tabela ou em algum lugar.

Então no caso seria uma paginação mesmo? se for, geralmente faço manipulando dados da database, por php e não jquery, porém já fiz uma vez com jquery... aqui é mais ou menos um exemplo, *adaptei da 'codetube'*, para dar alguma idea, espero que ajude:

*é recomendado colocar classes ativas para identificar qual page está atualmente, colocar com os dados da API real, no caso ajax é a melhor solução utilizando a API. Então coloca quantos quer por página no select ou em algum outro elemento ou deixa fixo 10.*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>teste</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- paginação -->

    <div class="container">
        <h4>Número de Linhas</h4>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select name="state" id="maxRows" class="form-control" style="width:100px;">
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="25" selected="">Tudo</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <span>obs: valores estáticos</span>
        <table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Esporte</th>
                    <th>Casa</th>
                    <th>Visitante</th>
                </tr> 
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <!-- simulando varios dados com php, porém na web vai pegar apenas1 no exemplo-->
                <!-- <?php for($i=0;$i<25;$i++){ ?> -->
            <!--<tr>
                    <td>Bundesliga 2</td>
                    <td>Darmstadt 98</td>
                    <td>Erzgebirge Aue</td>
                </tr> -->
                <tr><td>Bundesliga 2</td><td>Darmstadt 98</td><td>Erzgebirge Aue</td>
                <tr><td>Bundesliga 2</td><td>Darmstadt 98</td><td>Erzgebirge Aue</td>
                <tr><td>Bundesliga 2</td><td>Darmstadt 98</td><td>Erzgebirge Aue</td>
                <tr><td>Bundesliga 2</td><td>Darmstadt 98</td><td>Erzgebirge Aue</td>
                <tr><td>Bundesliga 2</td><td>Darmstadt 98</td><td>Erzgebirge Aue</td>
                <tr><td>Bundesliga 2</td><td>Darmstadt 98</td><td>Erzgebirge Aue</td>
                <tr><td>Bundesliga 2</td><td>Darmstadt 98</td><td>Erzgebirge Aue</td>
                <tr><td>Bundesliga 2</td><td>Darmstadt 98</td><td>Erzgebirge Aue</td>
                <tr><td>Bundesliga 2</td><td>Darmstadt 98</td><td>Erzgebirge Aue</td>
                <tr><td>Bundesliga 2</td><td>Darmstadt 98</td><td>Erzgebirge Aue</td>
                <tr><td>Bundesliga 2</td><td>Darmstadt 98</td><td>Erzgebirge Aue</td>
                <tr><td>Bundesliga 2</td><td>Darmstadt 98</td><td>Erzgebirge Aue</td>
                <tr><td>Bundesliga 2</td><td>Darmstadt 98</td><td>Erzgebirge Aue</td>
                <tr><td>Bundesliga 2</td><td>Darmstadt 98</td><td>Erzgebirge Aue</td>
                <tr><td>Bundesliga 2</td><td>Darmstadt 98</td><td>Erzgebirge Aue</td>
                <tr><td>Bundesliga 2</td><td>Darmstadt 98</td><td>Erzgebirge Aue</td>
                <tr><td>Bundesliga 2</td><td>Darmstadt 98</td><td>Erzgebirge Aue</td>
                <tr><td>Bundesliga 2</td><td>Darmstadt 98</td><td>Erzgebirge Aue</td>
                <tr><td>Bundesliga 2</td><td>Darmstadt 98</td><td>Erzgebirge Aue</td>
                <tr><td>Bundesliga 2</td><td>Darmstadt 98</td><td>Erzgebirge Aue</td>
                <tr><td>Bundesliga 2</td><td>Darmstadt 98</td><td>Erzgebirge Aue</td>
                <tr><td>Bundesliga 2</td><td>Darmstadt 98</td><td>Erzgebirge Aue</td>
                <tr><td>Bundesliga 2</td><td>Darmstadt 98</td><td>Erzgebirge Aue</td>
                <tr><td>Bundesliga 2</td><td>Darmstadt 98</td><td>Erzgebirge Aue</td>
                <tr><td>Bundesliga 2</td><td>Darmstadt 98</td><td>Erzgebirge Aue</td>
                </tr>
            <!-- <?php } ?> -->
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <!-- paginação -->
        <div class="paginator-container">
            <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li style="cursor: pointer;" class="paginacao"><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- paginacao -->
<script>
    var table = '#table';
    $('#maxRows').on('change', function(){
        $('.paginacao').html('')
        var trnum = 0
        var maxRows = parseInt($(this).val())
        var totalRows = $(table+' tbody tr').length
        $(table+' tr:gt(0)').each(function(){  
            trnum++
            if(trnum > maxRows)
                $(this).hide()
            if(trnum <= maxRows)
                $(this).show()
        })

        if(totalRows > maxRows){
            var num_pagina = Math.ceil(totalRows/maxRows)
            for(var i=1;i<num_pagina;){
                $('.paginacao').append('<a data-page="'+i+'">'+ i++ +'<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>').show()
            }
        }

        $('.paginacao a').on('click',function(){
            var num_pagina = $(this).attr('data-page')
            var trIndex = 0;
            $(table+' tr:gt(0)').each(function(){
                trIndex++
                if(trIndex > (maxRows*num_pagina) || trIndex <= ((maxRows*num_pagina)-maxRows)){
                    $(this).hide()
                }else{
                    $(this).show()
                }
            })
        })
    })
    $(function(){
        $('table tr:eq(0)').prepend('<th>ID</th>')
        var id = 0;
        $('table tr:gt(0)').each(function(){
            id++
            $(this).prepend('<td>'+id+'</td>')
        })
    })
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Olá novamente. eu fui ver mais a fundo sobre a API então depois de estudar um pouco mais, percebi algumas coisas. Ela retorna somente 8 jogos, os que estão acontecendo e os que estão pra vir. porém é atualizada assim que acaba ela retorna mais.

Acessando agora ali os comentários que fiz, coloquei alguns links. dos jogos de amanha, então da para checar hoje. Percebi que amanhã tem 5 jogos, então tem (3) jogos que são da segunda divisão da liga. Deixei as informações mais claras.

Então creio eu que você possa recuperar estes jogos e filtrar melhor, separando as divisões e/ou adicionando os outros valores que precisa. O lado bom que apenas 8 dados dinâmicos fica melhor trabalhar na tela. sem necessitar da paginação e sim apelar pro front-end mesmo. Espero ter ajudado mais uma vez :)

*obs: sugiro copiar o código pro seu editor, que na extensão de código fica sem word-wrap dificultando a leitura dos comentários.*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>teste</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- 
    Estudando a API : https://the-odds-api.com/liveapi/guides/v3/#overview
    creio eu que a API só mostre 8 recentes, que estão acontecendo ou que vai acontecer, no caso, os jogos de hoje e os jogos de amanha.

    Nesse exato momento, acabou todos os jogos de hoje; então aparece 8, que são 5 da bundesliga de acordo com liga US;

    //==================
    sport   The sport key obtained from calling the /sports method. upcoming is always valid, returning any live games as well as the next 8 upcoming games across all sports 

    Aqui o site que vi os jogos para conferir
    
    https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1NDCM_pt-BRBR787BR787&ei=bXnNXvCVJ6a85OUPmsyXiAw&q=bundesliga&oq=bundesliga&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIKCAAQgwEQRhD9ATIFCAAQgwEyBQgAEIMBMgUIABCDATIFCAAQgwEyBQgAEIMBMgUIABCDATIFCAAQgwEyAggAMgUIABCDAToECAAQR1CQ6QNYqPADYILxA2gAcAF4AIABgAGIAfMHkgEDMS44mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiwgOXQrNLpAhUmHrkGHRrmBcEQ4dUDCAw&uact=5#sie=lg;/g/11fk0cxp0k;2;/m/037169;mt;fp;1;;


    Então pro código json:
    //========================
    https://api.the-odds-api.com/v3/odds/?apiKey=e2d83afb38831daf6779f63a47c32d38&sport=upcoming&region=us&mkt=h2h
    
    Pode colocar diretamente no navegor, recomendo o plugin do JSONView para ver organizado os dados. Então aqui apareceu os jogos de amanha 27/05 e mais 3 jogos da bundesliga2 que é a 2º divisão; em geral, no site da bundesliga são no máximo 5 jogos por dia. Então creio eu que vai aparecer os jogos que estão acontecendo, logo depois que acabar um, vai vir outro upcoming de hoje/amanha;

    percebi que a API key free tem limite de requisição, então tem que tomar cuidado se for free a sua. (500 requests per month)

-->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- SCRIPT PRINCIPAL -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dadosJson = $.getJSON("https://api.the-odds-api.com/v3/odds/?sport=upcoming&region=us&mkt=h2h&apiKey=e2d83afb38831daf6779f63a47c32d38#", function(retorno){

        $.each(retorno.data, function (i) {
            times = retorno.data[i].teams;
            home_team = retorno.data[i].home_team;
            console.log('|=====Jogo=====|')
            console.log(times);
            console.log('Time da casa: '+home_team);
            console.log('');
        })
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isso Mesmo @joao-pedro-maciel, muito obrigado!

Comment: Aproveitando @João Paulo Maciel, teria como eu exibir apenas 10 resultados?

Comment: Show, isso mesmo que estava imaginando! Muito Obrigado @João-Pedro-Maciel

Comment: Boa tarde! @João-Pedro-Maciel, eu preciso é trazer somente 15 registros mais recentes, que vão acontecer ou estão acontecendo,  não preciso de uma paginação e nem guardar os valores. 
Poderia me ajudar? Obrigado

Comment: Bom dia @João-Pedro-Maciel, isso mesmo, esta API então é limitada pelo plano FREE, muito obrigado pelas claras respostas!

Comment: Bom dia, espero ter realmente ajudado :)